# How to reconstruct original BLOB value back from string?

Tags: c

Here's a function which converts BLOB to string (e.g. X'1234')

```
static void output_hex_blob(FILE *out, const void *pBlob, int nBlob){
  int i;
  char *zBlob = (char *)pBlob;
  fprintf(out,"X'");
  for(i=0; i<nBlob; i++){ fprintf(out,"%02x",zBlob[i]&0xff); }
  fprintf(out,"'");
}
```

How to reconstruct the BLOB value back from its string representation?
Thanx!

Comment: Is `nBlob` a known value at the time you want to reconstruct BLOB?

Comment: Yes, it is the structure size

Comment: Then, it's easy. You just read the first two characters and discard them. Then read the given number of characters using `"%02x"` format. Then read one more character and discard it. Try it out and see how it goes. If you are still stuck, come back with more information.

Comment: @RSahu: Or maybe better verify them instead of discarding them.

Comment: @MOehm, agree with you.

Comment: In fact I would check that without the `'X'` and the 2 single quotes the length is a multiple of two also.

Comment: Yes, I can parse the string the way you have proposed! But then I'm baffled! I have struct MyStruct's variable . Using output_hex_blob() I save it in a file. Then I need to reconstruct this structure from the file. I need some function str_to_blob() which takes string representation and returns (void *) so that I could use it as MyStruct *p = (MyStruct *) str_to_blob().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this function

```
void *
blobToBytes(FILE *input)
{
    unsigned char *data;
    char           byte[3];
    unsigned int   size;
    unsigned int   index;

    if (input == NULL)
        return NULL;
    fseek(input, 0L, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(input);
    rewind(input);

    byte[2] = '\0';
    if ((size - 3) % 2 != 0)
        return NULL;

    if ((fread(&byte, 1, 2, input) != 2) || (memcmp(byte, "X'", 2) != 0))
        return NULL;

    data = malloc((size - 3) / 2);
    if (data == NULL)
        return NULL;

    index = 0;
    while (fread(&byte, 1, 2, input) == 2)
        data[index++] = (unsigned char)strtol(byte, NULL, 16);

    return data;
}
```

Comment: Cool! That's just what I want!